# PHP access control from Android, iOS and Windowsphone

Tags: javascript, php, android, ios, cordova

I am creating a phonegap app for Android, Windows and iOs.
The app will be posting and accessing data from a php server using Post and Get request. the issue is due to Cross Domain Request restriction i have to allow access control with *.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 2000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
?>
```

I know this is a high security flaws. I will like to know how i can limit the access control only to android, windows phone and ios to increase the level of security.
I will be very glad if anyone can help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to check the User Agent in PHP. Each device has its own User Agent that you can compare with.

Know that it is possible to spoof the User Agent since it is also an HTTP header. The best thing for you would be to implement some sort of access control yourself without relying on which device it is coming from.

Comment: "implement some sort of access control yourself " any sample code on this or possibly a link of a sort on how to implement it? thanks

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. You could use some sort of token authentication using OAuth, or write your own custom authentication. It's really up to you. There is no cookie-cutter way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not you using `Hashing` method instead `Cross Origin`? Use `SHA-256`

Every time your API trigger some request, include hash.

Sample for javascript.

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>

<script>
  var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "secret");
  var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
  document.write(hashInBase64);
</script>
```

Reference: http://www.jokecamp.com/blog/examples-of-creating-base64-hashes-using-hmac-sha256-in-different-languages/#js

Comment: Thank you. but the thing is the server will not permit access due to the cross domain restriction.